# Publication on facebook App --> OK but invisible on facebook page

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, publish, restfb, facebook-java-api

I need to post a message from my facebook App to the facebook Page linked.
I explain how I do, please say me if it's no good. Thx.

1) I have created a facebook App.
So, I have a clientID and secretKEY.

2) I go on the advanced setting of my Application for create automatically the facebook page linked.

3) I execute this request in my browser :
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=clientID&client_secret=secretKey

So, now, I have an accessToken.

4) My Jave code (Note: I use Restfb) :

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("access_token");
facebookClient.publish("clientID/feed", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message", "wWwow!!!"));
```

5) My console say me :

```
21 mars 2012 15:12:39 com.restfb.DefaultWebRequestor executePost
INFO: Executing a POST to https://graph.facebook.com/********/feed with parameters (sent in request body): message=wWwow!!!&access_token=*******&format=json
21 mars 2012 15:12:40 com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient makeRequestAndProcessResponse
INFO: Facebook responded with HTTP status code 200 and response body: {"id":"******"}
```

So, I think that it's good and the status is really updated, no ?

**PROBLEM :** I see nothing on the facebook page linked with the application. Maybe I have to modify settings ? Or my code isn't good ?
Anyone can help me ?